# Internet Explorer High CPU usage

Tags: internet-explorer-11, cpu-usage, windows-server-2012-r2, terminal-services

**Situation and Problem:** We are working with Citrix + Windows Terminal Server 2012 R2 and we are  experiencing that a single Internet Explorer (Version 11.0.96) process can use up to 60-80% of CPU-Power. Since there are 15 user working on one Server any given time, one or two users can disturb all the others by using all the available CPU-Power.

**First (insufficient) Solution:** To overcome this Problem, We changed the Internet Explorer shortcut from the users startmenue (tile-design menue): We are starting the Internet Explorer just with three cores (out of 6 core) with this command:

start /Affinity 7 iexplorer.exe

Problem: If the users start the Internet Explorer from a link (out of word, Outlook or wherever), the Internet Explorer is starting again with all six cores.

**Question:** Is there a way to start the iexplorer.exe process (Independent from the starting point) always with less cores, or is it possible to limit the CPU-usage for a specific process..?

That's just two possibilities I'm thinking about, if you have other solutions in mind, feel free :)

Thanks and greetings Kevin

Answer (score 0):

Many reasons can cause this issue, Like due to issue in a update, due to homepage, due to add on.

So you need to check one by one that what thing cause this issue.

You can try steps below and check whether CPU consumption reduced or not.

(1) On the **General** Tab click **Tabs** button and **unchecked** the option "**Show Previews for individual tabs in the task bar**".

(2) Go to the "**Advanced**" tab in "**Internet Options**" and **checked** "**Use software rendering instead of GPU rendering**".

(3) Temporarily **disable** all the **add on** and turn on them one by one and check the consumed memory every time. If if you find any add on consume high CPU then remove it from IE.

(4) Try to check whether issue caused by a **faulty update**.

You can also try to refer **MSDN article** below and if you are using that specific update then try to apply the hot fix may solve your issue.

[Internet Explorer 11 consumes high memory and CPU cycles after you install update MS15-106](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3119070/internet-explorer-11-consumes-high-memory-and-cpu-cycles-after-you-ins)

Comment: Points 1-6 i've done, Point 7 I'm not sure how I should test this.
The link to the update MS15-106 doesn't work anymore, I guess because it is more than 3 years old, it is now part of Internet Explorer anyway.
I think more and more it is "normal": For example when loading https://www.blick.ch/ (crappy swiss news site ;) ) the CPU peaks for some seconds at 25%
With my IE on my private Laptop (not optimized with your points) it peaks around 40% CPU

That's why I'm thinking more about limiting the CPU resource from IE processes - if you have any idea how-to, would be amazing :)

Comment: You can try to reset the IE to check whether it helps or not. Also try to diagnose the CPU usage. To get instructions, you can refer link below. https://superuser.com/questions/1179273/why-is-ie-using-up-so-much-cpu